# Ajax not loading show server response issue

Tags: domain-name-system, wordpress, cache, ajax

i'm using lightspeed server when i hit a page it taking to much time to load ajax request while first it was working fine when i change DNS it slow down and lihgtspeed cache not working for loggedin users

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.